# Difference between Letter and Alphabet in English

Tags: alphabet

Can anyone please explain what is the difference between "Letter" and "Alphabet" in English?

Comment: This question can be answered by referring to an online dictionary. Could you at least explain why the two words confuse you?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have seen two terms being used interchangeably. SO just want to know what is the exact usage for these.

Comment: What was the phrase you read?

Comment: As oerkelens says, in English these terms are *not* interchangeable.

Comment: @Arvind07 the fault is yours for not explaining, one could say that without my asking for clarification, oerkelens would never have answered. You should always mention the dialect of English you are most familiar with, be it AmEng, BrEng, AuEng or InEng.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am not an English man, thats why I asked this simple question. You should not create so much fuss about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It may be worth noting that in *Indian English*, the word *alphabet* can take on a similar meaning to *letter*, which can cause confusion.

In standard English, the difference is basically that an alphabet is a *collection* of letters.

Answer (score 7):

A letter is a particular symbol used in writing, an alphabet is the set of all the letters.

Here is a letter: A

Here is an alphabet: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Comment: Seems to be valid, waiting for few more responses :)

Comment: It's a pretty basic question, so honestly not sure what extra you are after. If you want more info, the wikipedia page has a lot more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet

Comment: Just want to know if this is all or we have some other differences in terms of usage or so..

Comment: The terms are general, so in English we might refer to "the Hindi alphabet" or "the Greek alphabet", which refer to the collection of all the letters used in Hindi or Greek, respectively. If we refer to "a Hindi letter" or "some Greek letters", we are not referring to the whole alphabet, but just one or more letters in an alphabet.

Comment: Nice explanation.